# Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: constraint does not exist

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, migration

I'm trying to run Django migration in my project, but something is not working fine, and I couldn't figure out what could be happening.

The `AuditableModelMixin` entity is extended by almost all entities in my project and provides a couple of fields that are used for audit purpose. For all of than, the migrations is runing fine. Although, for the `Contract` model, the migration is creating the following two separated files:

#### 0001_initial.py

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Contract',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='identifier')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created at')),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='updated at')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='name')),
                ('description', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1024, null=True, verbose_name='description')),
                ('created_by', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, db_column='created_by', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='contract_created_by', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='created by')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'contract',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'contracts',
                'db_table': 'sacv"."contract',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

#### 0002_auto_20200524_1912.py (the sequence will change, that's ok)

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('contract', '0001_initial'),
        ('jurisdiction', '0001_initial'),
        ('state', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='contract',
            name='jurisdictions',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='contracts', through='jurisdiction.Jurisdiction', to='state.State'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='contract',
            name='updated_by',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, db_column='updated_by', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='contract_updated_by', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='updated by'),
        ),
    ]
```

I don't know why, it is putting the `updated_by` into a separated file. It start happening after I have added the `ManyToMany` relationship into `Contract` model. With this new approach, when I run the `python manage.py migrate`, I recieve the folling error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/sacv/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/sacv/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 480, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/fgv/sacv-p/src/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: constraint "contract_updated_by_4a62e48c_fk_account_id" does not exist

Error when trying create and run Django migrations!

Failed! The script execution has finished with errors!
```

If I change the migration file and put the `updated_by` into the first file, everything goes fine, but I don't believe that is the correct approach. Does someone has any clue about this problem?

The following code are the classes related with the problem:

### Audit Class

```py
class AuditableModelMixin(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _('created at'),
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'account.Account',
        verbose_name=_('created by'),
        db_column='created_by',
        related_name='%(class)s_created_by',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _('updated at'),
        auto_now=True,
    )
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'account.Account',
        verbose_name=_('updated by'),
        db_column='updated_by',
        related_name='%(class)s_updated_by',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

### Contract Class

```py
class Contract(
    UUIDModelMixin,
    AuditableModelMixin
):
    jurisdictions = models.ManyToManyField(
        State,
        related_name='contracts',
        through='jurisdiction.Jurisdiction',
        through_fields=('contract', 'state')
    )
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(
        _('description'),
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sacv\".\"contract'
        verbose_name = _('contract')
        verbose_name_plural = _('contracts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

### Jurisdiction Class

```py
class JurisdictionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            active=True, ended_at__isnull=True
        )


class Jurisdiction(
    UUIDModelMixin,
    EligibilityModelMixin,
    AuditableModelMixin
):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(
        Contract,
        verbose_name=_('contract'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    state = models.ForeignKey(
        State,
        verbose_name=_('state'),
        related_name="+",  # Disable the reverse relation for State
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    objects = JurisdictionManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sacv\".\"jurisdiction'
        verbose_name = 'jurisdiction'
        verbose_name_plural = 'jurisdictions'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.contract.name}: {self.state}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was happening due a problem where the schema was not being propagated when creating the constraints. This has been fixed and now it works like a charm. For further information, please check the bug [#31735](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31735)